# Oracle Recursive INNER JOIN with Child ID

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I'm working on a product database which has this structure :

```
ID | ChildID
1    1
2    2
2    3
2    4
2    5
3    null
4    8
5    6      
6    null
8    null
```

When ID = ChildID it's a "header" row.
When ChildId = null it's the last node in the hierarchy (obviously)
What i want to get is the full hierarchy.
I've tried some queries with the 'WITH' clause but i can't make it work due of the structure of it.

Any advice?

expected output when i look for the hierarchy of item '2'

```
ID | ChildID
2    2
3    null
4    8
5    6      
6    null
8    null
```

Comment: So, what's the expected output?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by getting the whole hierachy? I mean what kind of result do you want? a recordset? If so what would each record contain?

Comment: Is this an intersection (junction) table?  That is, are ID and CHILD_ID links to another table?  Either way, it is an unusual way to structuring things.  Most hierarchies are defined by the child linking back to its master.

Comment: I've edited question. This is not an intersection table.

Comment: So in the expected output, where does the `2,2` line come from? Just synthesize it because 2 was the root in the query? And the `8,null` line? It looks like 6 and 8 are both leaves, but the input has a distinction between them (6 has a null child and 8 doesn't) which is not maintained in your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to have a link between a 'header' row and any data. Assuming you're missing a row with `(1, 2)`, is this what you want?

```
select rpad(' ', 2*(level-1)) || id as padded_id, childid
from t42
start with childid = id
connect by nocycle prior childid = id
order by id, childid;

PADDED_ID     CHILDID
---------- ----------
1                   1 
  1                 2 
    2               3 
    2               4 
    2               5 
      3               
      4             8 
      5             6 
        6             

 9 rows selected
```

You can read about [hierarchical queries in the docuemntation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries003.htm).